# Good examples of Winform UIs - from a UX and aesthetic standpoint

Tags: .net, winforms, user-experience

Can anyone recommend some good online resources that show samples of what would be considered good Winforms "design" in terms of both **User Experience** and overall **aesthetics**. I'm looking for something that includes screenshots so as to *inspire* *me.....* not just a bullet list of best practices. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) is probably the most-used WinForms application in the "real world", which I would say qualifies it for consideration. Aesthetically, it is fairly plain, but I find it very intuitive.  [Screenshots are here](http://www.getpaint.net/screenshots.html).

Answer (score 1):

For inspiration, take a look at the [Infragistics Quince UX](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/main) site.  It may not necessarily all fit your WinForms criteria, but there is a wealth of information in there whether you have Infragistics or not.